Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using for Gradle
i can't run my project and everytime i tried i receive a message telling me that

my project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that
Flutter is using for Gradle

i tried to change my gradle version to one compativble with the java version that my flutter project is using but it didn't work.
Based on the command line :
flutter doctor --verbose 

My java version is :

Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)

i use android studio


This question is similar to: my project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using for Gradle. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I already tried but it didn't work. I think it's because my java version is too high but i wasn't able to downgrade it

What is the "it" that you already tried?

change my gradle version to be compatible with my java version

I think i need to downgrade my java version but i dont know how. I use android studio

You should start with updating your gradle. As per compatibility matrix your project should use at least 8.5 version.
To update, there are several options:

run updater in console with ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 8.5 or gradlew.bat wrapper --gradle-version 8.5 (windows) in project's android directory
Update distributionUrl in gradle.properties (on the screenshot in the question) to distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip

After that make sure that version of AGP (com.android.application) is at least 8.3.2. But newer is better I guess.
After that build should work again.

already tried and it return me this : BUILD FAILED in 12s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
PS C:\Users\kerby\StudioProjects\langcall\android> ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 8.5

Task :gradle:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.


BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\Path\flutter_windows_2.2.2-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\app_plugin_loader.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 65


Can you check second option and update gradle.properties file? Gradle wrapper command is basically doing the same, but it tries to configure project first and fails on that. Kind of chicken-egg situation

Is worse. I receive that : warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':connectivity_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':connectivity_plus:androidJdkImage'.


that's great actually, cause you solved first error and that is another one. Now you should update versions of AGP and Kotlin plugins. com.android.application should be at least 8.3.2 and org.jetbrains.kotlin.android should be at least 1.9.20

And maybe this to app/build.gradle: groovy tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile) {     kotlinOptions {         jvmTarget = "1.8"     } } if you encounter something like Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'compileReleaseKotlin' (21).

i don't understang how to put groovy tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile) {     kotlinOptions {         jvmTarget = "1.8"     } } in the build.gradle file

Try this: https://gist.github.com/Sameri11/b51da31c8105daba735c65859d1e1e78. Just copy-paste to your app/build.gradle

i tried but i still have an error :  Execution failed for task ':flutter_callkit_incoming:compileDebugKotlin'.

Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (17).


I sent in your url my full build.gradle code

answered there, check please

i have the same error
